# React Antt design editable table to add date picker not working

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

Im using My react type script project for **[ant design editable table](https://3x.ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row)**. when im try to add date picker , its not working correctly, anyone know how to do that correctly

Thanks

Code here.

**EditableTable.tsx**

```
// tslint:disable:no-any
import {DatePicker, Popconfirm, Table} from 'antd';
import React from 'react';

import {EditableCell} from "app/components/ServiceLevelAgreementComp/EdiatableCell";
import { EditableFormRow } from './EditableRow';
import { ColumnProps } from 'antd/lib/table';

export const EditableContext = React.createContext({ form: {} });
const data: any[] = [];

    data.push({
        key:1,
        name: `Edrward `,
        dateandtime: `2020-5-4 `,

    });

interface State {
    data: any;
    editingKey: any;
}
interface ColumnPropsEditable<T> extends ColumnProps<T> {
    editable?: boolean;
}

export class EditableTable extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    private columns: Array<ColumnPropsEditable<any>>;
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data, editingKey: '' };
        this.columns = [
            {
                title: 'Service',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                width: '150',
                editable: true,

            },
            {
                title: 'Date',
                dataIndex: 'dateandtime',
                width: '100',
                render: (key: any, rec: any) => {
                    return (
                        <span>

                            <DatePicker />

              </span>
                    );
                },
                editable: true
            },

            {
                title: 'Action',
                width: '100',
                dataIndex: 'operation',
                render: (text: string, record: any) => {
                    const editable = this.isEditing(record);
                    return (
                        <div>
                            {editable ? (
                                <span>
                                    <EditableContext.Consumer>
                                        {form => (
                                            <a
                                                href="javascript:;"
                                                onClick={() => this.save(form, record.key)}
                                                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                                            >
                                                Save
                                            </a>
                                        )}
                                    </EditableContext.Consumer>
                                    <Popconfirm
                                        title="Sure to cancel?"
                                        onConfirm={() => this.cancel()}
                                    >
                                        <a>Cancel</a>
                                    </Popconfirm>
                                </span>
                            ) : (
                                <a onClick={() => this.edit(record.key)}>Edit</a>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }
        ];
    }

    public isEditing = (record: any) => record.key === this.state.editingKey;

    public cancel = () => {
        this.setState({ editingKey: '' });
    }

    public save(form: any, key: any) {
        form.validateFields((error: any, row: any) => {
            if (error) {
                return;
            }
            const newData = [...this.state.data];
            const index = newData.findIndex(item => key === item.key);
            if (index > -1) {
                const item = newData[index];
                newData.splice(index, 1, {
                    ...item,
                    ...row
                });
                this.setState({ data: newData, editingKey: '' });
            } else {
                newData.push(row);
                this.setState({ data: newData, editingKey: '' });
            }
        });
    }

    public edit(key: any) {
        this.setState({ editingKey: key });
    }

    public render() {
        const components = {
            body: {
                row: EditableFormRow,
                cell: EditableCell
            }
        };

        const columns = this.columns.map((col: any) => {
            if (!col.editable) {
                return col;
            }
            return {
                ...col,
                onCell: (record: any) => ({
                    record,
                    inputType: col.dataIndex === 'dateandtime' ? 'any' : 'date',
                    dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
                    title: col.title,
                    editing: this.isEditing(record)
                })
            };
        });

        return (
            <Table
                components={components}
                bordered
                dataSource={this.state.data}
                columns={columns}
                // rowClassName="editable-row"
            />
        );
    }
}
```

**EditableRow.tsx**

```
// tslint:disable:no-any
import { Form } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
import { EditableContext } from './EditableTable';

const EditableRow = ({ form, index, ...props }: any) => (
    <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
        <tr {...props} />
    </EditableContext.Provider>
);

export const EditableFormRow = Form.create()(EditableRow);
```

**EdiatableCell.tsx**

```
// tslint:disable:no-any
import {DatePicker, Form, Input,} from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
import { EditableContext } from './EditableTable';

const FormItem = Form.Item;

export class EditableCell extends React.Component<any, {}> {
    public getInput = () => {
        if (this.props.inputType === 'string') {
            return   <DatePicker/>;
        }
        return <Input />;
    }

    public render() {
        const {
            editing,
            dataIndex,
            title,
            inputType,
            record,
            index,
            ...restProps
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <EditableContext.Consumer>
                {(form: any) => {
                    const { getFieldDecorator } = form;
                    return (
                        <td {...restProps}>
                            {editing ? (
                                <FormItem style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                                    {getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
                                        rules: [{
                                            required: true,
                                            message: `Please Input ${title}!`
                                        }],
                                        initialValue: record[dataIndex]
                                    })(this.getInput())}
                                </FormItem>
                            ) : restProps.children}
                        </td>
                    );
                }}
            </EditableContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}
export const EditableFormCell = Form.create()(EditableCell);
```

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker receives a moment object.

install the moment library if it's not already the case

```
npm install moment
```

Make sure to import the dll at the beginning of your file

```
import moment from "moment"
```

in your EdiatableCell.tsx file, update your FormItem:

```
<FormItem style={{ margin: 0 }}>
    getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
       rules: [{
          required: true,
          message: `Please Input ${title}!`
       }],
       initialValue: moment(record[dataIndex])
    })(this.getInput())}
</FormItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling for the last 5 days ... and found a solution to the problem ... below is a working code and I hope someone will use it to solve his problem.

the issue was with the object format that you need to supply to the datePicker as well to the render function.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table, Popconfirm, Form, Typography, DatePicker } from "antd";
const originData = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  originData.push({
    key: i.toString(),
    date: moment("2012-01-11T12:32:26.551Z", moment.ISO_8601),
  })
}

const EditableCell = ({
  editing,
  dataIndex,
  title,
  inputType,
  record,
  index,
  children,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const dateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";
  console.log(record);
  return (
    <td {...restProps}>
      {editing ? (
        <Form.Item
          name="date"
          style={{
            margin: 0
          }}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: `Please Input ${title}!`
            }
          ]}
        >
          <DatePicker
            
            format={dateFormat}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </td>
  );
};

const EditableTable = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [data, setData] = useState(originData);
  const [editingKey, setEditingKey] = useState("");

  const isEditing = (record) => record.key === editingKey;

  const edit = (record) => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      date: '',
      ...record
    });
    setEditingKey(record.key);
  };

  const cancel = () => {
    setEditingKey("");
  };

  const save = async (key) => {
    try {
      const row = await form.validateFields();
      const newData = [...data];
      const index = newData.findIndex((item) => key === item.key);

      if (index > -1) {
        const item = newData[index];
        newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...row });
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      } else {
        newData.push(row);
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      }
    } catch (errInfo) {
      console.log("Validate Failed:", errInfo);
    }
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "date",
      dataIndex: "date",
      width: "15%",
      editable: true,
      render: (_, record) => new Date(record.date._i).toLocaleDateString('en-US')    },

    {
      title: "operation",
      dataIndex: "operation",
      render: (_, record) => {
        const editable = isEditing(record);
        return editable ? (
          <span>
            <a
              href="javascript:;"
              onClick={() => save(record.key)}
              style={{
                marginRight: 8
              }}
            >
              Save
            </a>
            <Popconfirm title="Sure to cancel?" onConfirm={cancel}>
              <a>Cancel</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          </span>
        ) : (
          <Typography.Link
            disabled={editingKey !== ""}
            onClick={() => edit(record)}
          >
            Edit
          </Typography.Link>
        );
      }
    }
  ];
  const mergedColumns = columns.map((col) => {
    if (!col.editable) {
      return col;
    }

    return {
      ...col,
      onCell: (record) => ({
        record,
        inputType: col.dataIndex,
        dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
        title: col.title,
        editing: isEditing(record)
      })
    };
  });
  return (
    <Form form={form} component={false}>
      <Table
        components={{
          body: {
            cell: EditableCell
          }
        }}
        bordered
        dataSource={data}
        columns={mergedColumns}
        rowClassName="editable-row"
        pagination={{
          onChange: cancel
        }}
      />
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<EditableTable />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28401452)